# Creating Selenium network run via docker for firefox node in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, geckodriver

I am trying to run a docker image (E.g: webwhatsapi)  over Selenium network.
I followed below commands:

```
docker network create selenium

docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 --name firefox --network selenium -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-firefox-debug

docker build -t webwhatsapi .

docker run --network selenium -it -e SELENIUM='http://firefox:4444/wd/hub' -v $(pwd):/app  webwhatsapi /bin/bash -c "pip install ./;pip list;python sample/remote.py"
```

On AWS, I have following configuration in security group.

[image]

I am trying to open the http://{public ip}:4444 in firefox browser. It shows error. (This site can't be reached). I think, I should change my last command in a way which makes it work in browser url.
Last command:

```
docker run --network selenium -it -e SELENIUM='http://firefox:4444/wd/hub' -v $(pwd):/app  webwhatsapi /bin/bash -c "pip install ./;pip list;python sample/remote.py"
```

Please let me know, where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Hope you are running the two containers in the same instance. I have replicated the same in my environment and I could see **Selenium Standalone** page. Have you checked if you are editing the right security group associated with the instance in question?

Comment: Please add some info about your network configuration. 1) From your docker containers can you access any public I.P. (and website) - this will tell if your Gateway is configured. 2) When using multiple containers, do you need each container to have a static I.P to be publicly accessible from the internet, or can you rely on internal I.P. s provided by amazon to access your docker containers from other containers?